A (may be) trivial claim
I have a infinite sequence of (non negative) integers $(p_0, p_1,\ldots )$  and exist some $N>0$ such that $i>N \Rightarrow p_i=0$.
I define the function  $\Phi(i, m)$ where $i, m$ are (non negative) integers, as so:
Let $i_0:=i,\ \Delta_0=m$.
go to the  index $i_1=i_0+\Delta_0=i+m$ ; make the sum of the $\Delta_0$-elements after $p_{i_0}$:  $\Delta_1:=p_{i+1}+\ldots +p_{i+m}$
go on index $i_2:=i_1+\Delta_1$, make  the sum of the  $\Delta_1$-elements after $p_{i_1}$:   $\Delta_2:=p_{i_1+1},\ldots, p_{i_1+\Delta_1}$ ;
go on index $i_3:=i_2+\Delta_2$, make the sum of the $\Delta_2$-elements after $p_{i_2}$: $\Delta_3:=p_{i_2+1}+\ldots, +p_{i_2+\Delta_2}$
$\ldots$
and so on until I get the first $k$ such that $\Delta_{k}=0$  then put
$\Phi(i, m):=i_k$.
the elements involved in each of the $\Delta_1,\ \Delta_2,\ldots \Delta_k$ make finite interval of the sequence and these intervals are disjoint and consecutive, then $\Phi(m)=i+m+p_{i+1}+p_{i+2}+\ldots p_{\Phi(m)}$ (and $p_{\Phi(m)}=0$).
I claim that $\Phi(i, m)$ is a non decreasing function in $m$ (then by the formula above is strictly non decreasing).
I see that seem trivial (by induction for example),  but I couldn't prove it precisely (maybe because of the too warming of these days here).
I asking for a proof of the claim.
I'm interesting to case $(p_1,\ldots, p_N, 0,0\ldots)$ such that $p_1+\ldots+p_N=N-1$ and $p_j+p_{j+1}+\ldots p_N\leq N-j$ for $j=1,\ldots, N$.
Thank in advance.

if $i + m_0 = N$, then wouldn’t $\phi(i, m_0) > \phi(i, m_0 + 1)$? Or am I misunderstanding something?
